# Adding custom application in sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I was trying to find layout Studio to create a custom App in sitecore 7.2, but couldnt find it. Did anyone try any customization in sitecore 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is now referred to as the Developer Center.
`Sitecore Start Button > Development Tools > Developer Center`

I wouldn't recommend using this if you have access to other development tools that are more suited to the task To be honest I'm surprised Sitecore have kept this feature in the product.

Comment: As of 7.1 sitecore is deprecating the developer center anyways: [Sitecore is deprecating the Developer Center application. The application is still available in 7.1, but will be removed in a later release. We recommend that developers use Sitecore Rocks instead.](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with Layout Studio, I have never noticed it ;)
If you want to create a custom application, you have 3 choices, all of them use Visual Studio for your coding:

- use XAML/SheerUI to create your application ([sheer ui reference](http://markstiles.net/Blog.aspx?tag=Sheer%20UI))
- use SPEAK ([Speak reference](http://www.dervalp.com/creating-your-first-speak-page/)) allthough Speak seems to be changing heavily in Sitecore 8.
- use standard WebForms or MVC

Which one you choose, mostly depends on personal preferences and the functionality you need.
I mostly prefer using standard WebForms or MVC because of the flexibility.